# Is C++11's std::thread compatible with POSIX semaphores?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I want to use threads in my C++ application by using the standard C++ std::thread library, however y wanted to use semaphores and using the C++20's semaphores wasn't possible, I wanted to know if POSIX semaphores <semaphore.h> is compatible with C++ STD's Threads or I have to change my code in order to use POSIX threads

Comment: The C++ standard makes no mention of POSIX semaphores, but what exactly do you mean by "compatible"?

Comment: It is not compatible in the sense that I would use the term "compatible".  You may be able to expose the underpinnings (assuming on your platform they are POSIX threads) and interop with those internals with POSIX semaphores; it may be an educational journey.

Comment: Do POSIX semaphores block std::threads?, or POSIX semaphore can only block POSIX threads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard library will implement std::thread as a wrapper over pthreads on POSIX systems, so using <semaphore.h> would be fine. Semaphores are usually implemented regardless of the specific threading interface, though the C standard library may do some book-keeping at the same time using pthreads.

For this reason, calling `sem_wait()` from a thread (whether it be a `pthread_t` or an std::thread) will have the same effect, though it may be better to just use pthreads, as they would be the most "compatible", especially since you are only targeting POSIX systems anyway.